# spotify api getting artists

Tags: node.js, spotify

I'm trying to get top artists from each of the last twenty years. I looped over the years by passing the current iteration to the spotify endpoint as a dynamic value. Here in the code 'x' is the array of artists. I need all the artists in a single array but I am getting the response for each iteration in a different array. (check picture for the output). how can I fix this?

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
let { userAccessToken } = require('./spotifyConfig')

async function getArtists() {
        try {
    for (let i = 2000; i < 2020; i++) {
            let data = await fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=year%3A${i}&type=artist&market=US`, {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${userAccessToken}`
                }
            })
            let actualData = await data.json()
            var allItems = actualData.artists.items
           var x = allItems.map(item => {
                var everyOne = item.name
                return everyOne
            })
           console.log(x)
        } 
    } catch (e) { console.log (e) }
}



getArtists()
```

[image: here is the output]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please incorporate full or part of your json file into your post so people could see both code and data in single page.

Answer (score 0):

Input is different in every iteration so logically its fine to get the different response right, are talking about response structure??

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you are not capturing the data outside of the loops so every time it iterates the values are reset. You need to declare a results array to store each iteration in and return that at the end.

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
let { userAccessToken } = require('./spotifyConfig')

async function getArtists() {
    const result = []
        try {
            for (let i = 2000; i < 2020; i++) {
                    let data = await fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=year%3A${i}&type=artist&market=US`, {
                        method: "GET",
                        headers: {
                            Authorization: `Bearer ${userAccessToken}`
                        }
                    })
                    let actualData = await data.json()
                    var allItems = actualData.artists.items
                var x = allItems.map(item => {
                        var everyOne = item.name
                        return everyOne
                    })
            result.push(x)
            } 
            return result.flat()
        } catch (e) { console.log (e) }
}
getArtists()
```